# Alignment in dynamically allocated array of pointers to pointers to ints

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have this function that generates a "3D array" (I know it's not actually a 3D array but it is a nice way to understand it for me):

```
int*** generate_test_arrays(int test_arrays_length, int array_values_from,
    int array_values_to, int arrays_per_length) {
    /*This function returns a dynamically allocated "3D array" (a pointer to it).*/
    int*** test_arrays = new int**[test_arrays_length];
    for (int i = 0; i < test_arrays_length; i++) {
        /*printf("Group %d:\n", i + 1);*/
        test_arrays[i] = new int*[arrays_per_length];
        for (int j = 0; j < arrays_per_length; j++) {
            test_arrays[i][j] = new int[i + 1];
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < i + 1; i2++) {
                test_arrays[i][j][i2] = (i2 < i) ? rand() % (array_values_to - array_values_from + 1) + array_values_from: array_values_to + 1;
                /*cout << test_arrays[i][j][i2] << " ";*/
            }
            /*cout << endl;*/
        }
        /*cout << endl;*/
    }
    return test_arrays;
}
```

And I need each array of integers (i. e. each `test_arrays[i][j]`) to be 16 byte aligned, but I don't know what alignment actually is and neither do I know how to align my arrays. Does anyone know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `test_arrays[i][j][i2]` is of type `int`. You sure you want every `int` to be 16 byte aligned?

Comment: oh I'm so sorry, I meant every `test_arrays[i][j]` to be 16 byte aligned. I edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: "I don't know what alignment actually is and neither do I know how to align my arrays." I hate to have to ask such an obvious question, but have you tried searching? Alignment is fairly basic stuff. Your class probably has information on it somewhere, and if not, previous questions on SO or the wider internet should be informative. At least I assume this is classwork, since this kind of pseudo-C++ pointer explosion is rarely necessary in real-life code.

Comment: I know I can align with `__declspec(align(16))`, but I don't know how to insert it in the triple loop. I tried typing it before `test_arrays[i][j]` but it doesn't work like that. This is part of a homework that is not at all aimed at aligning, so I guessed there was nothing wrong with asking.